# Problems using Card-img-overlay with card-columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 4.4 to create a card column:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Problems using Card-img-overlay with card-columns</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="card-columns" style="padding-top: 2%;">

            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1920x1080" style="opacity: 65%;">
              <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
      
            <div class="card bg-danger text-white mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">
                Cabeçalho do cartão
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">
                Cabeçalho do cartão
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
      
            
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
      
            <div class="card">
      
              <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="">Link 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="">Link 3</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
        
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4>Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6>Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
              
            </div>
      
      
            <div class="card bg-success text-white mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">
                Cabeçalho do cartão
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
      
          </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem is with the card I use Card-img-overlay. When the screen has a higher resolution, the display occurs as expected:

[image: Working]

When the screen is smaller:

[image: Part of the casing omitted and image does not fit]

Part of the meat and its contents are omitted. I tried padding top but it doesn't work properly.

Besides, I can't seem to make the image fit. I tried for a vertically larger image but all I can get is that the card occupies the space corresponding to the height of the image.

How do I prevent the content from being overlaid by another card? and so that the image occupies all the space of the card always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `bootstrap` way to impliment this idea is not the best one. Element with `position: absolute` is taking out of `DOM` and can't be fit with it's content.

I suggest to replace `.card-img-overlay` with `.card-body` and instead of `<img>` make `div` with image as it's background and parametrs as in snippet.

```css
.bg-img {
  opacity: 65%;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1920x1080);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bg-img + .card-body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Problems using Card-img-overlay with card-columns</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="card-columns" style="padding-top: 2%;">

    <div class="card">
      <div class="bg-img"></div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card bg-danger text-white mb-2">
      <div class="card-header">
        Cabeçalho do cartão
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-2">
      <div class="card-header">
        Cabeçalho do cartão
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="">Leia mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">

      <div class="card-header">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Título do cartão</h4>
        <h6>Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block" href="">Leia mais</a>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="card bg-success text-white mb-2">
      <div class="card-header">
        Cabeçalho do cartão
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="">Leia mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the parent div element of card-img-overlay is not set to relative and has no fixed height. Set a minimum height for the parent div element (which is .card) so that it will not shrink when the viewport gets smaller.

```
  .card {
    min-height: 300px;
    position: relative; 
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svwb6r31/